# Wondering why I have to replace ':' with ',' in my code

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments, chatbot

I am following a youtube tutorial on how to build a chatbot using python + javascript and it's telling me in certain places to use ':' instead of ','. For example "(selectors: '.chatbox__button')".

Here's my app.js code:

```
class Chatbox {
     constructor() {
        this.args = {
           openButton: document.querySelector(selectors: '.chatbox__button'),
           chatBox: document.querySelector(selectors: '.chatbox__support'),
           sendButton: document.querySelector(selectors: '.send__button'),

        }

        this.state = false; 
        this.messages = [];
     }

     display() {
        const {openButton, chatBox, sendButton} = this.args;

        openButton.addEventListener(type: 'click', listener: () => this.toggleState(chatBox))

        sendButton.addEventListener(type: 'click', listener: () => this.onSendButton(chatBox))

        const node = chatBox.querySelector(selectors: 'input');
        node.addEventListener(type: "keyup", listener: ({key: string}) => {
             if (key == "Enter") {
                this.onSendButton(chatBox)
             }

        })
     }



}
```

However I get like 10 errors saying :
',' expected. ts(1005) [Ln6, Col 56]

[image: Here are my errors if you want to see in a picture:]

I am wondering why in the tutorial it works, but I can't seem to place ':' without getting any errors in my own code?

Comment: `document.querySelector(selectors: '.chatbox__button')` is not valid JavaScript. `document.querySelector('.chatbox__button')` is. Similar with `addEventListener`. Besides that, in `if (key == "Enter")` the variable `key` is not defined; you should be testing `string` instead there.

Comment: (My advice is to learn JavaScript first, with a reputable source, e.g. with [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), so you will know when a random YouTube tutorial is being sketchy.)

Comment: Which tutorial? Are you sure they aren't using some code generator/transtyper? Like typescript is (tho I am not aware that typescript allows this argument naming more than JS does. But, I mean, typescript is a transtyper that allows as input some syntax that are not valid javascript. So, there might be others that add this argument naming thing)

Answer (score 1):

<I'll leave my answer since i spent 30 min writing hoping it works for you or anyone else with similar problem>

**TL:DR:** Learn the basics first as @Amadan said.

**Technical answer:**
In javascript,  functions you don't set the "name" of function parameters, you just respect the order that the parameters are valid for that function.

So, instead of calling functions like this:

```
//Example A:
openButton: document.querySelector(selectors: '.chatbox__button'),
//Example B:
openButton.addEventListener(type: 'click', listener: () => this.toggleState(chatBox))
//Example C: 
node.addEventListener(type: "keyup", listener: ({key: string}) =>
```

You should them like this, **without the parameter names, just the values being set:**

```
//Example A: 
//1 parameter
openButton: document.querySelector('.chatbox__button')

//Example B: 
//2 parameters (1: type of event, 2: arrow function to be called when event is triggered)
openButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleState(chatBox)) 

//Example C: 
//2 parameters (1: on keyboard "keyup" event, 2: another arrow function to be called when event happens)
node.addEventListener("keyup", ({key}) => ...
```

</I'll leave my answer since i spent 30 min writing hoping it works for you or anyone else with similar problem>

Happy coding!

Comment: `{key: string}` [destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter of the function by looking up the key named `key` and storing the value into a variable named `string`; `string` is not a declaration of type. It is the same destructuring as in `const {b: c} = {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz"}` being equivalent to `const c = "bar"`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. To typefy a destructured object would be `{foo,bar}:{string,number}`. Then foo is string and bar is number. https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/